# Global method this.$t from vue-i18n does not work in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I define vue-I18n globally:

```
Vue.use(VueI18n);
export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'cs',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'cs',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

I can use it anywhere with:

```
this.$t('sign-up.something-went-wrong')
```

But not inside a for each loop, probably because new anonymous class is created. How can I reference it from there?

```
function convertErrors(jsonErrors) {
  const veeErrors = {};
  console.log(this.$t('sign-up.heading'));
  return veeErrors;
}
```

And called from `export.default`

```
methods: {
  async submitForm() {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$store.dispatch('CREATE_USER_PROFILE', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        nickname: this.nickname,
      });

      if (!this.personalData) {
        this.success = true;
        return true;
      }

      if (data.token === undefined) {
        this.error = this.$t('sign-up.something-went-wrong');
        return false;
      }

      const jwtData = jwtDecode(data.token);
      const vehicles = [];
      setVehicles.call(this, vehicles);
      await this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_USER_PROFILE', {
        jwt: data,
        userId: jwtData.userId,
      });
      this.success = true;
    } catch (error) {
      this.success = false;
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(this.$t('sign-up.something-went-wrong')); // this works
        const veeErrors = convertErrors(error.response.data); // this fails
        this.$refs.form.setErrors(veeErrors);
      } else {
        this.error = this.$t('sign-up.something-went-wrong');
      }
    }
    return this.success;
  },
},
```

I can see the following error in the chrome console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined"
```

And

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined
at convertErrors (SignUpForm.vue?9fa9:236)
at VueComponent._callee$ (SignUpForm.vue?9fa9:321)
at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:45)
```

Comment: Where is `jsonErrors.errors.forEach` being called? `this` inside the arrow function depends on where that function is declared.

Comment: from within form handler>     async submitForm() {

Comment: Can you paste more of your code? difficult to say where the problem is.

Comment: This part works: this.$t('sign-up.something-went-wrong');

Comment: But that part does not: this.$refs.form.setErrors(convertErrors(error.response.data));

Comment: Why don't you define `convertErrors` in Vue methods? Or bind `this` to `convertErrors`

Comment: Because I am JS/Vue newbie. This is the complete code: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/spa/src/components/molecules/forms/SignUpForm.vue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`convertErrors` has no "this", it's not bound to a component. Move it into the component's `methods` in order to reference `this`:

```js
methods: {
  convertErrors(jsonErrors) {
    const veeErrors = {};
    console.log(this.$t('sign-up.heading'));
    return veeErrors;
  }
}
```

OR

use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) in order to set the context (the `this`) inside `convertErrors`:

```js
const veeErrors = convertErrors.call(this, error.response.data);
```

Comment: When I move the function inside methods and before the submitForm, WebStorm complains it is undefined here: const veeErrors = convertErrors(error.response.data); and it shows the method as unused.

Comment: If you move it inside `methods` then you have to call it via `this.convertErrors` (add a `this.`) because it will be moved to the component instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store VueComponent before for each loop. Like this one:

```
let self = this
// .......
jsonErrors.errors.forEach((error) => {
  if (error.field) {
    veeErrors.$field = [self.$t(error.messageKey)];
  } else {
    self.error = self.$t(error.messageKey);
  }
});
```

Comment: The arrow function ensures `this` is the same inside the function as where the function is declared. The `let self = this` will give the same reference as the original code.

Comment: I was trying to say we can store VueComponent before `this` keyword changes his meaning in future scope.

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: With arrow functions, `this` inside the function is always the same as the `this` where the function was declared. Your code ends up with the same effect.

Comment: You are right. I tried to call it before the loop and it does not work there either. I need to investigate the call stack.